# SSIS 2012 File Paths

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

I am using SSIS 2012 to perform a couple basic tasks. The issue I am having occurs in both a `Process Execute` task and a `Flat File` connection. When developing the file is local, but I am using an expression to replace the file directory once deployed. I have the files, which are a CSV and a BAT file in the "Miscellaneous" folder.

I would like to be able to reference the relative path of the files rather than an explicit directory on my computer. This would also prevent other developers from having to stage the files locally before being able to even validate the package.

Comment: Project deployment model?

Comment: You can do this by assigning a variable.

Comment: @billinkc, Yes project deployment model.

Comment: @Maverick, how to make that work when the project is running locally and initially validating?

Comment: You can Create 2 variables in Package/Project scope depending upon your model. 1 variable: Folderlocation, 2 variable: and it dynamic which you can click to variable properties > Expression and Do yourFilename with extension.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Project Parameter as your folder path.. and use it in your expression Something like

@[$Project::FileLocation]  +@[User::FileName]

Comment: To add to this, there are some more detailed instructions and pictures available here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlgardner/2015/06/18/ssis-tip-using-a-file-path-parameter-for-multiple-flat-files/
To capture the gist - Create a "FileLocation" parameter on the project... And open a package, select a Connection Manager, then in the Properties box, find the "Expressions" row, and click the "...", then select the field and create the expression for it in the Expression Builder from the variables as JCurious mentions above.